# 500 Internal Server Error only in public_html?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hosting

I'm encountering 500 Internal Server Errors on my shared hosting account, but only when I try and access PHP files in my main root public_html directory.  Any PHP files in subdirectories are absolutely fine.

Permissions all appear to be set correctly across all files (all set to 755).  Rewrite engine is on in .htaccess with a single re-write rule which has nothing wrong with it, but to be sure I've deleted all the rules there and the problem persists.

The error logs show this every time I try and access a file:

```
[07-Sep-2014 16:15:36 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
 library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - 
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

The warning repeats for every `.so` file that needs to be loaded.  All HTML files and image files work fine in the root directly, it's only PHP files that cause the problem.

As it's shared hosting I can't restart Apache, but other than that I have full access to edit `php.ini`.

How can I fix this please?

**Additional Information:**

I did not notice this before, but I also get this error:

`[07-Sep-2014 16:15:36 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: As loading libraries can't be done directory specific, this problem is rather weird. Are you sure this error messages are related to the 500 you are getting? They are warnings, not errors (so they should not lead to 500), and are generated on PHP startup...

Comment: Hi, I have just noticed one actual error rather than a warning: `[07-Sep-2014 16:15:36 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0`.
Does this make any more sense? Thanks for your help

Comment: It does. That directive was removed with PHP > 5.4. It was deprecated to use that feature before.

Comment: Just to double-check: are you also seeing the error when running a file containing just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in the `/public_html` directory? Is there an `.htaccess` file in that directory which might be doing something which is overridden elsewhere? Or, if you're using Apache, is there a `<directory>` directive which is doing something special just for `/public_html`?

Comment: I see, it was built on 5.4 so my host must have updated without telling me.  I've commented it out of my `php.ini` file now and it seems to have fixed the problem.
Thanks for your help, post an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Hi Gavin, it seems to have been the `allow_call_time_pass_reference` issue.  Having it disabled doesn't seem to have had any negative effect on the other folders, although I'm still confused as to why anything worked at all outside of the root directory with this enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In old versions of PHP, you were able to pass variables to functions by reference by proceeding the variable with a `&` sign, even if the function did not specify its arguments to be passed as reference. This feature could be controlled using the directive [`allow_call_time_pass_reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.allow-call-time-pass-reference). Using it was deprecated since PHP 5.0 and was removed in 5.4.

Remove it form your `php.ini` and the error should be gone.

If you need to pass variables by reference, specify the function parameters to be passed by reference in the first place, or nest your values in arrays as an unclean but working altnerative.